# Test automation on VB6 and WPF

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, vb6-migration

We have a application built on a VB6 framework that contains wpf control elements.
I am looking for a test automation tool able to identify both VB6 and wpf objects.

We have QTP in house but we have mixed results.

Comment: What do you mean by "be able to identify" ?

Comment: Our application in based on VB6 but has UI components that are WPF some are activated directly and some are VB6 controls that have WPF inserts. QTP is able to recognize the VB6 components with ease but the WPF in vb frames are encapsulated so we cannot get the internal properties.

Answer (score 0):

I work in the project where application is written in vb6 and also uses WPF controls which are exported to COM and used in a vb6 application. As I know there have been made some prototypes with tools such TestStack.White and Ranorex but results where unsatisfied.

Current tool which is under evaluation is a TestComplete. This tool provides quick writing tests and handle hybrid application written in vb6 + WPF quite well. It looks promising, maybe it will be used for test automation.

I never used QTP, so I can't tell if it is better or not, but you could look at TestComplete and compare. There is a trial available.